# Magento 2 : Alter core observer functionality

Tags: magento2, event-observer, magento-2.1, reports

I am trying to add a new value "merchant_id" in

```
\module-reports\Observer\CatalogProductViewObserver.php
```

How i can override `save` by add new data to save to it

```
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId();

        $viewData['product_id'] = $productId;
        $viewData['store_id']   = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $viewData['customer_id'] = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
        } else {
            $viewData['visitor_id'] = $this->_customerVisitor->getId();
        }

        $this->_productIndxFactory->create()->setData($viewData)->save()->calculate();

        $this->eventSaver->save(\Magento\Reports\Model\Event::EVENT_PRODUCT_VIEW, $productId);
    }
```

I Need to add `$viewData['merchant_id']` and assign value to it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options:

**1) Disable the default observer and add our custom observer - events.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="catalog_controller_product_view">
            <observer name="reports" disabled="true"/> <!--Disable default observer-->
            <!--Add our custom observer-->
            <observer name="reports_custom" 
              instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CatalogProductViewObserver" />
        </event>
    </config>
```

**2) Can override - preference - di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Reports\Observer\CatalogProductViewObserver" type="Vendor\Module\Observer\CatalogProductViewObserver" />
```